# parse php array and choose item based on condition

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving album photos from facebook's graph api. 
This code does the trick, however i am trying to select the **smallest thumbnail that equal 130 and above width:130 x height:130**

meaning the width OR height has to be 130 and above,  NOT the sum of width and height.
**note:** the array list are image variation from facebooks album, so they would be in proportion.  so if it is a portrait or landscape dimension it would scale in dimension accordingly.

So from the `print_r` below you can see the in the first array, item (2) fits that description, but the other arrays would be numbers (2) and (1) since this is the smallest above 130 width/height

```
$userURL2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/$albumID/photos?access_token=" . $fb_oAuth_token;
$ch2 = curl_init($userURL2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
$pictures = json_decode($data2, true);

print_r($pictures);
```

output from `print_r($pictures);`

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 288
                        [width] => 460
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )
        [1] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 200
                        [width] => 320
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

        [2] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 130
                        [width] => 180
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

        [3] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 81
                        [width] => 130
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

)

Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 500
                        [width] => 500
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 500
                        [width] => 500
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

        [2] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 480
                        [width] => 480
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )


)
Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 335
                        [width] => 300
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                        [height] => 335
                        [width] => 300
                        [source] => https://myurl.jpg
                )


)
```

**question**: How would i write this in php?

```
foreach($pictures['data'] as $picture){

    $width = $picture['width'];
    $height = $picture['height'];

    // choose the smallest [source] above width:130 x height:130

}
```

Comment: Does this need to be based on total number of pixels? Or purely on one or other dimension being above 130? Which is the smaller? width = 140, height = 140; or width = 130; height = 200?

Comment: Where are you getting the 'data' index from? (disregard last edit, didn't read closely enough)

Comment: @vanamerongen - I'd guess from Facebook graph API

Comment: @vanamerongen getting 'data' from FB's graph api - album

Comment: @MarkBaker i am trying to find the smallest image 130 pixels and above width AND height

Comment: So in my example, it would be the width = 140, height = 140 image?

Comment: That print_r output makes no sense? Can you do that again and make sure you show all of it.

Comment: @MarkBaker  hi,  where are you getting 140 from?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `print_r` from fb's api different lenght values per album.  what doesnt make sense?

Comment: Surely it should be wrapped in another Array or a Class?? You cannot have 3 seperate arrays output from one variable!!

Comment: @tq - I asked, which would you'd want if you have 2 entries, one 130x200, the other 140x140 - it's not in your sample data, but you might get such dimensions from dynamic data in the future

Comment: @MarkBaker oh i see what you mean,  in that case the 130x130 since this is the smaller of the 2,  and the condition is 130 and above

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you want me to `print_r` from the parent `foreach` loop, yes these are arrays nested but is this important for this question?

Comment: @tq But what he means to say is that that one *isn't* the smallest. The 140 x 140 is the smaller one of the two in total. The 130 x 200 only has a smaller height. So you need to figure out if you want the smallest one in terms of width, height, or total pixels.

Comment: @vanamerongen  thanks for that!  let me re do my question

Comment: Hehe, you're still not getting it I don't think. We're talking about once you have *done* the check to see if it's above 130 width and height, *what* do you consider the smallest thumbnail. Do you consider the smallest thumbnail the one width the smallest height or the one width the smallest width? Or do you consider the total pixels the smallest? Or do you mean the smallest value in either? Cause if so, you could have 130 width and a 30000 height (if you want, lol) count as smaller than a thumbnail of 131 width x 135 height, which is silly.

Comment: @vanamerongen im so sorry about that,  the images are variations of the same image from album so it would be in proportion so there would never be such difference

Comment: @tq Heh, don't worry about it. Understand the confusion. If that's the case then you could use the example I gave in my answer, which checks for total size. But if the proportions stay the same, you may as well only check for only one of the values (width or height) and leave out the $size variable (still talking about *after* the check for > 130 width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may work for you. It will return the smallest pic that satisfies the min width/height or false if none of the pictures satisfy.

```
$test = array(
    0 => array(
        'height' => 288,
        'width' => 460,
        'source' => 'https://myurl.jpg'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'height' => 81,
        'width' => 130,
        'source' => 'https://myurl.jpg'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'height' => 200,
        'width' => 320,
        'source' => 'https://myurl.jpg'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'height' => 130,
        'width' => 180,
        'source' => 'https://myurl.jpg'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'height' => 100,
        'width' => 120,
        'source' => 'https://myur5.jpg'
    )
);


$pic = getTheRightPic($test, 130, 130);

var_dump($pic);


function getTheRightPic($pictures, $min_width, $min_height)
{
    //get one to start with
    do
    {
        $win_pic = array_pop($pictures);
    }
    while ( ! checkXY($win_pic, $min_width, $min_height));

    //if none of the pic satisfies return false
    if ($win_pic === false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($pictures as $pic)
    {
        $win_pic = comparePics($win_pic, $pic, $min_width, $min_height);
    }

    return $win_pic;
}

function comparePics($original, $compare, $min_width, $min_height)
{
    if ( ! checkXY($compare, $min_width, $min_height))
    {
        return $original;
    }

    //calculate sizes
    $original['size'] = $original['width'] * $original['height'];
    $compare['size']  = $compare['width'] * $compare['height'];

    //return the smaler pic
    if ($original['size'] > $compare['size'])
    {
        return $compare;
    }

    return $original;
}

function checkXY($pic, $min_width, $min_height)
{
    if ($pic['width'] < $min_width && $pic['height'] < $min_height)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: in your test,  if you change the min_width to 131 you get a false `$pic = getTheRightPic($test, 131, 130);`

Comment: Nope, just got 130X180.

Comment: oh,  its in the array,  when i added another value `,4 => array(
        'height' => 100,
        'width' => 120,
        'source' => 'https://myur5.jpg'
    )`  it broke

Comment: @t q adding that array does break it, so I edited to correct.

Comment: from the sample above,  it chose array(1) ,  it should be array(2) because array(1) height is smaller than 130

Comment: In that case just change this line like ($pic['width'] < $min_width || $pic['height'] < $min_height) so both height and width must meet the requirement. Now condition is satisfied if at least one satisfies.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code for you, we are first setting up a picture array to compare against that has very large dimensions, we are then looping though your arrays arrays to find an image that has both the width and height that is greater then 130 but the area is less then the selected image.

```
$selectedPicture = array('width' => 10000, 'height'  => 10000, 'source' => '');

foreach($pictures as $album){
    foreach($album as $picture){
        if($picture['width'] > 130 && $picture['height'] > 130 && ($picture['width'] * $picture['height']) < ($selectedPicture['width'] * $selectedPicture['height'])){
            $selectedPicture = $picture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @tq `$selectedPicture['source']`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? I think this works, but I haven't tested.

```
$thumbnail = array();                // array to store the smallest thumbnail over 130 x 130 in

foreach($pictures['data'] as $key => $picture){
    if($picture['width'] > 130 && $picture['height'] > 130){        // Check if thumbnail has height AND width over 130.
        $size = $picture['width'] * $picture['height'];     // Store total pixel size since the check for > 130 width and height was already done anyway.
        if(!isset($thumbnail['index'])){               // Check if there's a thumbnail already stored,
            $thumbnail['index'] = $key;                // and if not, store this one
            $thumbnail['size'] = $size;
        } elseif($thumbnail['size'] > $size) {         // Check if currently stored thumbnail is bigger,
            $thumbnail['index'] = $key;                // And if it is, store this one
            $thumbnail['size'] = $size;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you should have the smallest thumbnail over 130 x 130 px stored in the $thumbnail array if I'm not mistaken.

e: Oh, btw, I mean you have the array *referring* to one of the thumbnails stored in the original array. You wouldn't be storing the whole thumbnail, but I guess you could just do that by adding 'url', 'width', and 'height' indexes to it.

e2: Also, this takes into account the *total* pixel size to check for smallest. Like Mark said in his comment, it's unclear if you want the total pixel size to be the smallest one or the width/height.

Comment: thank you for all this,  but it isnt choosing the correct one

Comment: Hm, well, all I can say is: it checks if it's over 130 height and width and it then checks for the smallest total size of the picture. Go through every line and read the comments for each thing it does, then see if that's what you actually want it to store.

Comment: thanks i got it to work,  but on some of them the `$picture['width'] > 130 && $picture['height'] > 130`  && doesnt seem to be filtering properly.  its allowing smaller height to get thru